# forloop inside dplyr mutate

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, mutated

I would like to do a few column operations using mutate in more elegant way as I have more than 200 columns in my table that I would like transform using mutate.

here is an example

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(treatment=rep(letters[1:2],10),
c1_x=rnorm(20),c2_y=rnorm(20),c3_z=rnorm(20),
c4_x=rnorm(20),c5_y=rnorm(20),c6_z=rnorm(20),
c7_x=rnorm(20),c8_y=rnorm(20),c9_z=rnorm(20),
c10_x=rnorm(20),c11_y=rnorm(20),c12_z=rnorm(20),
c_n=rnorm(20))
```

sample code:

```
dfm<-df %>%
mutate(cx=(c1_x*c4_x/c_n+c7_x*c10_x/c_n),
cy=(c2_y*c5_y/c_n+c8_y*c11_y/c_n),
cz=(c3_z*c6_z/c_n+c9_z*c12_z/c_n))
```

Comment: "to do the following" is awfully vague, requiring readers to trudge through your code, y'know. You could use words to describe it.

Comment: You should `melt` so that you can do a grouped operation on the `x`, `y`, `z` groups.  (Actually, from your example, it might be straight-up column arithmetic after melting.)

Comment: agree with @Gregor; you could also `tidyr::gather()` (hadleyverse 2) instead of `reshape2:melt()`ing (hadleyverse 1)

Comment: @BenBolker, there are *two* hadleyverses now? Is this some kind of dimensional rift or many worlds thing?

Comment: Theoretically, aren't their *infinite* hadleyverses? We've only discovered two of them. We're just a [mere simulation](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/227126-neil-degrasse-tyson-says-its-very-likely-the-universe-is-a-simulation).

Comment: Does that mean there's a hadleyverse where you're allowed to make pie charts and second y-axes with ggplot2?

Comment: in case it's not obvious, hadleyverse 1 = (plyr, reshape2, ggplot2); hadleyverse 2 = (dplyr, tidyr, rvest, readr, ..., ggvis?).  I don't know about the original versions of reshape and ggplot (primordial chaos?)

Comment: Wouldn't it be our luck that the hadleyverse where the entire world uses the metric system is the same hadleyverse that allows pie charts. :(

Answer (score 3):

Despite the tangent, the initial recommendations for using `tidyr` functions is where you need to go. This pipe of functions seems to do the job based on what you've provided.

Your data:

```
df <- data.frame(treatment=rep(letters[1:2],10),
                 c1_x=rnorm(20), c2_y=rnorm(20), c3_z=rnorm(20),
                 c4_x=rnorm(20), c5_y=rnorm(20), c6_z=rnorm(20),
                 c7_x=rnorm(20), c8_y=rnorm(20), c9_z=rnorm(20),
                 c10_x=rnorm(20), c11_y=rnorm(20), c12_z=rnorm(20),
                 c_n=rnorm(20))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

This first auxiliary data.frame is used to translate your `c#_[xyz]` variable into a unified one. I'm sure there are other ways to handle this, but it works and is relatively easy to reproduce and extend based on your 200+ columns.

```
variableTransform <- data_frame(
  cnum = paste0("c", 1:12),
  cvar = rep(paste0("a", 1:4), each = 3)
)
head(variableTransform)
# Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#    cnum  cvar
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1    c1    a1
# 2    c2    a1
# 3    c3    a1
# 4    c4    a2
# 5    c5    a2
# 6    c6    a2
```

Here's the pipe all at once. I'll explain the steps in a sec. What you're looking for is likely a combination of the `treatment`, `xyz`, and `ans` columns.

```
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(cnum, value, -treatment, -c_n) %>%
  tidyr::separate(cnum, c("cnum", "xyz"), sep = "_") %>%
  left_join(variableTransform, by = "cnum") %>%
  select(-cnum) %>%
  tidyr::spread(cvar, value) %>%
  mutate(
    ans = a1 * (a2/c_n) + a3 * (a4/c_n)
  ) %>%
  head
#   treatment       c_n xyz         a1          a2         a3          a4         ans
# 1         a -1.535934   x -0.3276474  1.45959746 -1.2650369  1.02795419  1.15801448
# 2         a -1.535934   y -1.3662388 -0.05668467  0.4867865 -0.10138979 -0.01828831
# 3         a -1.535934   z -2.5026018 -0.99797169  0.5181513  1.20321878 -2.03197283
# 4         a -1.363584   x -0.9742016 -0.12650863  1.3612361 -0.24840493  0.15759418
# 5         a -1.363584   y -0.9795871  1.52027017  0.5510857  1.08733839  0.65270681
# 6         a -1.363584   z  0.2985557 -0.22883439  0.1536078 -0.09993095  0.06136036
```

First, we take the original data and turn all (except two) columns into two columns of "column name" and "column values" pairs:

```
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(cnum, value, -treatment, -c_n) %>%
#   treatment         c_n cnum      value
# 1         a  0.20745647 c1_x -0.1250222
# 2         b  0.01015871 c1_x -0.4585088
# 3         a  1.65671028 c1_x -0.2455927
# 4         b -0.24037137 c1_x  0.6219516
# 5         a -1.16092349 c1_x -0.3716138
# 6         b  1.61191700 c1_x  1.7605452
```

It will be helpful to split `c1_x` into `c1` and `x` in order to translate the first and preserve the latter:

```
  tidyr::separate(cnum, c("cnum", "xyz"), sep = "_") %>%
#   treatment         c_n cnum xyz      value
# 1         a  0.20745647   c1   x -0.1250222
# 2         b  0.01015871   c1   x -0.4585088
# 3         a  1.65671028   c1   x -0.2455927
# 4         b -0.24037137   c1   x  0.6219516
# 5         a -1.16092349   c1   x -0.3716138
# 6         b  1.61191700   c1   x  1.7605452
```

From here, let's translate the `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` variables into `a1` (repeat for other 9 variables) using `variableTransform`:

```
  left_join(variableTransform, by = "cnum") %>%
  select(-cnum) %>%
#   treatment         c_n xyz      value cvar
# 1         a  0.20745647   x -0.1250222   a1
# 2         b  0.01015871   x -0.4585088   a1
# 3         a  1.65671028   x -0.2455927   a1
# 4         b -0.24037137   x  0.6219516   a1
# 5         a -1.16092349   x -0.3716138   a1
# 6         b  1.61191700   x  1.7605452   a1
```

Since we want to deal with multiple variables simultaneously (with a simple `mutate`), we need to bring some of the variables back into columns. (The reason we `gather`ed and will now `spread` helps me with keeping things organized and named well. I'm confident somebody can come up with another way to do it.)

```
  tidyr::spread(cvar, value) %>% head
#   treatment       c_n xyz         a1          a2         a3          a4
# 1         a -1.535934   x -0.3276474  1.45959746 -1.2650369  1.02795419
# 2         a -1.535934   y -1.3662388 -0.05668467  0.4867865 -0.10138979
# 3         a -1.535934   z -2.5026018 -0.99797169  0.5181513  1.20321878
# 4         a -1.363584   x -0.9742016 -0.12650863  1.3612361 -0.24840493
# 5         a -1.363584   y -0.9795871  1.52027017  0.5510857  1.08733839
# 6         a -1.363584   z  0.2985557 -0.22883439  0.1536078 -0.09993095
```

From here, we just need to `mutate` to get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to r2evans's answer, but with more manipulation instead of the joins (and less explanation).

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# get it into fully long form
gather(df, key = cc_xyz, value = value, c1_x:c12_z) %>%
    # separate off the xyz and the c123
    separate(col = cc_xyz, into = c("cc", "xyz")) %>%
    # extract the number
    mutate(num = as.numeric(str_replace(cc, pattern = "c", replacement = "")),
           # mod it by 4 for groupings and add a letter so its a good col name
           num_mod = paste0("v", (num %% 4) + 1)) %>%
    # remove unwanted columns
    select(-cc, -num) %>%
    # go into a reasonable data width for calculation
    spread(key = num_mod, value = value) %>%
    # calculate
    mutate(result = v1 + v2/c_n + v3 + v4 / c_n)

#    treatment          c_n xyz           v1           v2            v3          v4        result
# 1          a -1.433858289   x  1.242153708 -0.985482158 -0.0240414692  1.98710285    0.51956295
# 2          a -1.433858289   y -0.019255516  0.074453615 -1.6081599298  1.18228939   -2.50389188
# 3          a -1.433858289   z -0.362785313  2.296744655 -0.0610463292  0.89797526   -2.65188998
# 4          a -0.911463819   x -1.088308527 -0.703388193  0.6308253909  0.22685013    0.06534405
# 5          a -0.911463819   y  1.284513516  1.410276163  0.5066869590 -2.07263912    2.51790289
# 6          a -0.911463819   z  0.957778345 -1.136532104  1.3959561507 -0.50021647    4.14947069
# ...
```